# Language files in a plugin

Tags: plugin, language

I'm writing a plugin that needs some translatable strings at runtime, but I'm having trouble getting my language file to be picked up.

I've got the following:

- `/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_myplugin.sys.ini`
  This contains the translations for the plugin's config page. This is working fine.
- `/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_myplugin.ini`
  This contains the translations for the plugin to use at runtime. This is not working.
- And both of the above referenced in the plugin XML file:

  ```
  <languages>
      <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_myplugin.sys.ini</language>
      <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_myplugin.ini</language>
  </languages>
  ```

As noted above, the .sys.ini file is working just fine; my plugins config page shows up with all the labels, etc loaded correctly.

However the .ini file is not working. From what as I can tell, looking at the Joomla Debug Console, the .ini translation file isn't being loaded at all even when the plugin is being used.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. Similar code in modules and components works just fine, but I can't make it work in a plugin.

Can someone please tell me how to make a language file work in a plugin, or tell me what I'm missing.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you put the file manually to the Joomla site or only via the zipped installation file? The plugin language files have to be placed into the directory /administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_myplugin.ini
Please add the content of the *.ini file too - maybe there is a failure in the language file itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Joomla 3.1 it is not necessary to expand the constructor any more, like farahmand's answer.
You can easily write / set the ***$autoloadLanguage*** like

```
 class myPlugin extends JPlugin
 {
    /**
    * Load the language file on instantiation.
    *
    * @var    boolean
    * @since  3.1
    */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    ...
```

Comment: In some specific situations we should still use the constructor to load language files; for example: whenever you want to write a `user` plugin and use `onUserAfterLogin` event to send an email or enqueue a message with translatable text. Using `protected $autoloadLanguage = true;` is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It seems too easy to be true, but I can confirm that it does work so I will accept this answer. However, I'd be interested to know if this is actually documented anywhere. It *isn't* in the documentation for writing a plugin (ie https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin/en, as suggested by @YolkNet), and I haven't seen it anywhere else, so I'm not sure how I could have discovered it without diving into the Joomla source code (I have done this plenty of times, but it's impractical to do it every time you need to know something).

Answer (score 3):

Load the language files in the plugin's constructor like so:

```
function __construct(&$subject, $config) {
    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $lang->load('plg_system_myplugin', dirname(__FILE__));

    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
}
```

Comment: it is more convinient to use autoloadLanguage see my additional answer.

Comment: @TomKuschel In some specific situations we should still use the constructor to load language files; for example: whenever you want to write a `user` plugin and use `onUserAfterLogin` event to send an email or enqueue a message with translatable text. Using `protected $autoloadLanguage = true;` is not enough.

Comment: @Farahmand - thanks for the answer, and for the comment. Can you expand the answer to include a bit of info about *why* `$autoloadLanguage` is not enough in some cases. What makes it okay for some things and not others? Thank you. I'll try both answers and will accept the one that works, but I have up-voted both already. Thanks for helping.

Comment: By the way... why are you using `dirname(__FILE__)` rather than `__DIR__`?

Comment: @Simba - You're welcome. Some points: You hadn't mention `Joomla 3.x` tag in your question and the accepted answer is only for Joomla 3.1+. Moreover if you have PHP 5.3.0+ you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`. In fact, if you are using Joomla 3.x, you can use `__DIR__` because the min PHP required is 5.3.1.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm on the latest J 3.x, and thus php >=5.3 (actually 5.6). To be honest, I didn't even think of specifying it because J 2.5 is so old now that I've pretty much forgotten that it even exists.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have done the following, but just to make sure:

- read https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin/en
- be sure the language file exists and in the right folder
- (double)check the language file is written with the right syntax and there is no misspelling

The problem can be in your language file or in your script. To determine this you can try to override a constant in your language file. Go to Extensions --> Languages --> Overrides and click on the green New-button. Search for a value that should be in the language file. If you don't get a result it's in your file. If you do get a result it's in your script.

Comment: Thanks for this. In fact, the correct answer was given by @TomKuschel, and isn't mentioned in the above documentation. It probably should be in there though. Even though your answer didn't help me directly, I am up-voting it because it is potentially useful for others looking for similar info. Thank you.